# Trying to write ordered dictionary to csv, but it comes out blank

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv, ordereddictionary

I'm very, very new to coding in general and Python in particular. I am trying to convert an ordered dictionary (at least, I think it is an ordered dictionary) into a csv file. When I do this, it does create the csv file but it is entirely blank, except for a "" in A1.

```
import sys
import csv
import json
import requests

def lookup(Name1, Name2):
    url = '<url for nested dictionary>'
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    results = data['results']['officers']
    for a in results:
        print( a['officer']['name'],a['officer']['company']['company_number'])


def from_file(filename):
    results = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            result = lookup(row['Name1'], row['Name2'])
            results.append(result)
    return results

with open('LabourDonorComp.csv', mode='w') as donor_file:
    donor_writer = csv.writer(donor_file, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    donor_writer.writerow(from_file(sys.argv[1]))
```

The code I am inputting into the terminal is

```
python3 BestFile3.py LabourDonorsP.csv
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please. Python is very space sensitive. You can highlight code and either press `{}` in the toolbar or `Ctrl+K` on the keyboard.

Comment: It looks like your `lookup()` function is not returning a value and is just printing some attributes.  When you call `results.append(result)` you're not actually appending anything because you're not actually assigning a value to `result` in the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lookup()` function returns `None` (more exactly: it doesn't explicitely returns anything, so it implicitely returns `None`. As a result (no pun intended), `from_files` returns a list of `None`. So the first thing to do is to fix `lookup()` so it returns the expected values. You'll probably have a couple other issues, but then it's another question...

Comment: Ok, thanks! Do you have any suggestion of what command I should be using instead of lookup()?

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand : **what you need to do is to fix `lookup()` so it returns what you expect**

Answer (score -3):

Try using the pandas library for this. You can create a `DataFrame` object and then export that to a `.csv.`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(ordered_dict)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Comment: Could Panda users learn to answer something else than "use panda" each time someone ask something about csv ? Thanks.

Comment: If you're on the question and a csv genius, go ahead and answer it yourself. I am simply letting him know that this is a way to solve the problem, and that it is how I would solve his problem. Thanks.(; @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: Not to mention that OP is new to python, so Pandas would be a GREAT library to start learning and manipulating .csv files

Comment: No need to be a genius to use the csv module, and even less to spot the issue. What you're suggesting is not "a way to solve the problem", it's a kludgy workaround at best. And being new to Python, what the OP needs most is to learn debugging his/her code.